# Add <br /> after insertAfter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following Javascript to place adsense ads between posts by identifying tags `blockquote` and `pre`. It works fine.

I also want to include a `<br />` after the advert. In essence I need to include `<br />` after `id='adsense-content'`

```js
function insertAfter(addition, target) {
  var parent = target.parentNode;
  if (parent.lastChild == target) {
    parent.appendChild(addition);
  } else {
    parent.insertBefore(addition, target.nextSibling);
  }
}

var adscont = document.getElementById(' adsense - content ');
var target = document.getElementById(' adsense - target ');
var linebreak = target.querySelectorAll(' blockquote, pre ');
var linebreak2 = target.querySelectorAll(' img ');

if (linebreak.length == 0) {
  insertAfter(adscont, linebreak2[0]);
} else {
  insertAfter(adscont, linebreak[Math.floor(linebreak.length / 2)]);
}
```

Comment: Could you please format your code so that it's readable ?

Comment: If it is within a `pre` tag, you can use `"+\n"` to include a newline character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be better if you would create the space using CSS.
But in case you want to create a new line break element and injecting it after the element with the id `adsense-content` you can do it by using `appendChild` function on the `adsense-content` element and append a newly created line break like so:

```
var adscont = document.getElementById("adsense-content");
var linebraek = document.createElement("br");
adscont.appendChild(linebraek );
```